# touchxml parser equal parser in Android?

Tags: android, parsing, sax, touchxml

touchxml parser in iphone is very quick , is there any such equal parser in android , or  a trick to have such quick parsing ?

Answer (score 0):

TouchXMLlequivalent in Android, there is none as far as i know.

You can use SAXParser for paesing XML Files.

[This Link might be of some help to you.](http://www.anddev.org/parsing_xml_from_the_net_-_using_the_saxparser-t353.html)